# spark read from mongodb

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

is there a better option to read from mongodb via spark? currently I use https://github.com/Stratio/Spark-MongoDB

Do I understand correctly that

```
val mongoRDD = sql.fromMongoDB(mongoConfigurationData)
    mongoRDD.registerTempTable("myTable")
```

is so slow because a lot of the data is scanned initially?
How can it be that

```
sql.sql("CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE myTable USING mongoConfigurationData)") seems to be slower?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can read from mongodb using [unity JDBC](http://www.unityjdbc.com/mongojdbc/mongo_jdbc.php)
and [MongoDB Java Driver](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/)

```
import mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver
```

Import the two classes SparkConf and SparkContext

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.{DataFrame, SQLContext}
```

Simply replace url with your mongodb url. 
dbtable with name of the table for which you want to create dataframe.
replace user and password for your db2 database server.

```
val url = "jdbc:mongo://ds045252.mlab.com:45252/samplemongodb"
val dbtable = "Photos"
val user = "charles2588"
val password = "*****"
val options = scala.collection.Map("url" -> url,"driver" -> "mongodb.jdbc.MongoDriver","dbtable" ->dbtable,"user"->user,"password"->password)
```

Now create new SQLContext from your new Spark Context which has db2 driver loaded

```
val sqlContext = new SQLContext(sc)
```

Create a dataframereader from your SQLContext for your table

```
val dataFrameReader = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").options(options)
```

Call the load method to create DataFrame for your table.

```
val tableDataFrame = dataFrameReader.load()
```

Call show() method to display the table contents

```
tableDataFrame.show()
```

Ref:
http://bigdataauthority.blogspot.com/2016/03/connecting-to-mongodb-from-ibm-bluemix.html

Thanks,

Charles.

Comment: hi, I get  a error Auth failed when I try to connect to mongodb in this way. after I add option "dbname" -> "admin", I can get access to mongodb. But it comes new error:
Error while sampling collection: system.profile.....  So that I get nothing in dataFrameReader. Any suggestion?